# Count number of lines in a caption

Tags: spacing, graphics, captions

I have a problem formatting my captions for figures/tables.

What should happen is the following: I need one line above the image and two lines above and below the caption. To make it look good, I have to adjust vertical spacing several times.

A problem now occurs depending on whether the caption is displayed in one or several lines. For single line captions I would need to adjust by the vspacing by `{-0.8 \baselineskip}`, in case of a multiline caption only by `{-0.1 \baselineskip}` for the line below the caption to have exactly the same space to the bottom of the text. I'm not so familiar with LaTeX or typesetting, so I don't understand why this happens at all. A solution would be to somehow figure out the number of lines in the caption, but I have no idea how to do this. I tried to "abuse" the `lineno` package for my needs, but without any success.

Has anyone an idea how to solve this or what causes the problem at all?

Below the code for my image insertion.

```
\newcommand{\includewrappedfigure}[6][0pt]{
% example params: [0pt]{R}{.3}{afigurefile}{figure with long caption}{fig:afigure}
    \begin{wrapfigure}{#2}{#3\textwidth}
    \centering
    \vskip -.8 \baselineskip
    \hrule
    \includegraphics[width=#3\textwidth, keepaspectratio]{#4}
    \vskip -1 \baselineskip
    \hrule
    \vskip -0.8 \baselineskip
    \caption{#5}
    \label{#6}
    \vskip -.1 \baselineskip % for MULTI line captions
    % \vskip -.8 \baselineskip % for SINGLE line captions
    \hrule
\end{wrapfigure}
}
```

Comment: Hi Stefan, welcome! It is not customary to sign in the post here, I have removed that. Have a great stay! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately you didn't supply a minimal working example, so I don't know if you are using a class that uses the same caption code as `article`, however article uses:

```
\long\def\@makecaption#1#2{%
  \vskip\abovecaptionskip
  \sbox\@tempboxa{#1: #2}%
  \ifdim \wd\@tempboxa >\hsize
    #1: #2\par
  \else
    \global \@minipagefalse
    \hb@xt@\hsize{\hfil\box\@tempboxa\hfil}%
  \fi
  \vskip\belowcaptionskip}
```

The `#1: #2\par` is the multi-line case, the `\hb@xt@\hsize{\hfil\box\@tempboxa\hfil}%` is the single line case, so you can redefine this command adding whatever spacing you need in each case.

Comment: Thanks, that gave me a great hint! I'm using KOMA-Script report-class and now found the \@@makecaption. It works essentially the same way (\ifdim-clause) and enables me to extend it with the necessary case-dependent line-drawing.